# What's the difference between "<" and "<<" in ruby in this use case?

Tags: ruby, oop, rubygems

From what I know "<"  is inheritance of a class from another class?

but I also see "<<" being used for the same thing from what I am seeing,.

Example:

```
def catch_alarm(alarm_info, options)
  alarms = []
  alarms << AlarmMonitor.new({
        region_id: region_name,
        account_id: '10202'.
        alarm_name: alarm_info
    },
  alarms
end
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the "class << Class" (angle brackets) syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33453063/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-class-class-angle-brackets-syntax)

Comment: It would be tremendously helpful for your future fellow software developers if you could explain what, precisely, is unclear to you about [the documentation of `Array#<<`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C). Only if you explain what is wrong with the documentation will the Ruby developers be able to improve it, so that future developers do not run into the same problems you did. You will essentially be making the world a better place, and who wouldn't want that?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `<` and `<<` are not the same.

Ruby – like many other programming languages – uses the [infix notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation) for [binary operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation), i.e.:

<kbd>left-hand side</kbd> <kbd>operator</kbd> <kbd>right-hand side</kbd>

For example:

```
1 + 2
a - b
i >= j
x << y
```

But unlike many other languages, operators are implemented as *methods* in Ruby. So it's actually:

<kbd>receiver</kbd> <kbd>method</kbd> <kbd>argument</kbd>

If you want to know, what `alarms << AlarmMonitor.new(...)` does, you have to know what kind of object `alarms` is. In your example, it's an array (`alarms = []`) so the method is [`Array#<<`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C):

> #### ary << obj → ary
>
> Append—Pushes the given object on to the end of this array. This expression returns the array itself, so several appends may be chained together.

Note that different objects (or classes) can implement the same operator in different ways:

```
a = [1, 2]
a << 3       # pushes 3 onto the array, i.e. [1, 2, 3]

d = Date.new(2020, 5, 28)
d << 3       # returns a date 3 months earlier, i.e. 2020-02-28

i = 0b00001011
i << 3       # shifts the bits 3 to the left, i.e. 0b01011000
```

The behavior primarily depends on the receiver.

---

Let's briefly get back to `<`. In addition to methods, Ruby has [keywords](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/keywords_rdoc.html). Keywords sometimes work like methods, but they have their own parsing rules.

For class creation, Ruby has the `class` keyword:

```
class MyClass
  # ...
end
```

Which accepts an optional subclass via:

```
class MySubclass < MyClass
  # ...
end
```

Here, `<` is not an operator, but part of the `class` keyword syntax.

However, there's also a `<` *operator* for classes: [`Module#<`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Module.html#method-i-3C). It can be used to check whether `MySubclass` is a subclass of `MyClass`: (thus mirroring the class creation syntax)

```
MySubclass < MyClass
#=> true
```

Answer (score 2):

In this context `<<` is the [Array push operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C), so isn’t related to the use of `<` for class inheritance.